# Azure Function Input Binding from CosmosDB: Will data loading occur on every call?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

In Azure Functions i can easily create an input binding to a Cosmos DB Connection and specify a SqlQuery to get some data passed into my function on every call as described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb#input---example-2

I'm wondering if this query is executed on every call of the function or if some sort of caching occurs behind the scenes (maybe even using ChangeFeed or some other mechanism to detect changes) ?

When the data coming from the query doesn't change very often, i guess querying the data myself and storing it in a static cache in my function would be more efficient.

Comment: your assumptions are right

Comment: yeah, checking requests to my cosmos db proves it as well. this should clearly be stated in the documentation imho

Comment: Yes, querying the data yourself and storing it in a static cache in function would be more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query will be executed every time.

Azure Functions have stateless nature. Even though some things can and should be reused between requests (e.g. connections to remote resources), for the most things you should assume that all loading will happen every time.

Depending on query results, caching each and every one of them could consume significant amount of memory. Remember that you pay for memory consumption.

Also, I am not sure if there is a way to cache the results of a custom Cosmos DB query and then have a reliable cache invalidation, even based on the change feed.

Overall, caching might be effective in your scenario, but it can't be effective in all scenarios. So, caching by default can't be a thing.

Comment: In my case the data used for processing the input data stream is reference data which is not likely to change very often (only when new devices are provisioned). So cache invalidation is no problem as i can safely cache the results for a couple of minutes and then rehydrate the cache as part of a new request. In my scenario, the performance boost by caching the input data was enormous and i can achieve 10-20x the throughput i got without caching.

Comment: I understand your comment regarding memory consumption, however this is currently no issue as the data is a flat list consuming max 2 MB. When this data would grow however i think a distributed cache like Redis would imho still be much more efficient than querying the data on every call. What do you think @Mikhail?

Comment: @MarkusS. I agree caching can make sense in many scenarios, and yours sounds like a good one. I just tried to explain why (IMO) it's not supported by default binding. You could make your implementation with cache on top.